# can I use Android phone without service to test app

Tags: android, eclipse, html, cordova

I have a Android phone without service. (no phone company I am using with it) Am I able to test my Android app with this phone? If yes what step I should go? I am using Eclipse using HTML5 and phoneGap to develop app.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "what step I should go?" but assuming your app doesn't use phone service (voice calls or SMS), then yes you could test your app on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Should work fine.

Just remember to connect to wifi if your app requires the internet in order to work.